# Equivalence between Dirac delta of a function to a usual Dirac delta

Tags: distribution-theory, dirac-delta

Let $f_1(s,\tau)=\delta(e^{(\tau+s)} \sinh \tau )$.

This should be equal to $0$ everywhere unless $\tau=0$, but I think there should be some constant multiplying the delta, i.e. it should be equivalent to $f_2(s,\tau)=c(\tau,s)\delta(\tau)$ where $c(\tau,s)$ is a constant.

How can I manipulate $f_1$ to resemble $f_2$?

Thanks.

Comment: Here's the [relevant section from wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dirac_delta_function#Composition_with_a_function). Also see http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/276583/dirac-delta-function-of-a-function

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Consider, for fixed $s$, the function
$$ g_s(\tau) = \exp(\tau + s)\sinh \tau $$
we have
$$ g_s'(\tau) = \exp(\tau +s)(\sinh\tau + \cosh\tau) = \exp(2\tau + s)$$
Hence, $g_s$ is monotone, therefore we have by substitution for $\phi \in C_c^\infty(\def\R{\mathbf R}\R)$:
\begin{align*}
  \int_\R f_1(s,\tau)\phi(\tau)\, d\tau
   &= \int_\R \delta\bigl(g_s(\tau)\bigr)\phi(\tau)\, d\tau\\
   &= \int_{-\exp(s)/2}^\infty \delta(x)\phi\bigl(g_s^{-1}(x)\bigr)\, g_s^{-1}{}'(x)\, dx\\
   &= \phi\bigl(g_s^{-1}(0)\bigr)g_s^{-1}{}'(0) 
\end{align*}
Now, as $g_s(0) = 0$, we have $g_s^{-1}(0) = 0$ and by the rule for the derivative of the inverse, we have 
$$ g_s^{-1}{}'(0) = \frac 1{g_s'(0)} = \frac 1{\exp(s)} $$
Hence, we may continue
\begin{align*}
  \int_\R f_1(s,\tau)\phi(\tau)\, d\tau
   &= \phi\bigl(g_s^{-1}(0)\bigr)g_s^{-1}{}'(0) \\
   &= \phi(0) \exp(-s)\\
   &= \int_\R \delta(\tau)\exp(-s)\phi(\tau)\, d\tau
\end{align*}
That is, 
$$ f_1(s,\tau) = \delta(\tau)\exp(-s). $$