# How to solve Dirac Delta function having 2 centres?

Tags: distribution-theory

$$\int_{-\infty}^\infty (x^2 + 1) \delta(x^2 - 3x + 2) dx =\ ?$$

Which property of Dirac Delta function can be used to solve this type of problems? Or can we call it a Dirac Delta function having two centres?

Comment: Would [math.se] be a better home for this question?

Comment: Just take a look of its properties, [link](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dirac_delta_function#Composition_with_a_function).

Answer (score 1):

As already pointed out you should take a look of the properties of the Dirac delta for the general case.

Nonetheless in this case your intuition gives the correct answer:

you can regard $\delta(x^2-3x+2)$ as $\delta(x-1)+\delta(x-2)$, where $1$ and $2$ are the roots of the polynomial $x^2-3x+2$.

The result is then simply achieved, and the original integral becomes:

$$\int_{-\infty}^{+\infty}(x^2+1)\delta(x-2) + \int_{-\infty}^{+\infty}(x^2+1)\delta(x-1) = (2^2+1)+(1^2+1) = 7$$

Comment: This is generally not correct: $\delta(x^2-3x+2)=|2x-3|^{-1} \left ( \delta(x-1) + \delta(x-2) \right )$. It is a coincidence here that $|2(1)-3|=|2(2)-3|=1$.

Comment: Correct, I guess I should have put more emphasis on this, thanks.

Answer (score 0):

$$\int_{-\infty}^\infty (x^2 + 1) \delta(x^2 - 3x + 2) dx=\int_{-\infty}^\infty (x^2 + 1) \delta((x-1)(x-2)) dx$$
$$=\int_{2-\epsilon}^{2+\epsilon} (x^2 + 1) \delta((x-1)(x-2)) dx+\int_{1-\epsilon}^{1+\epsilon} (x^2 + 1) \delta((x-1)(x-2)) dx$$
$$=2^2+1 + 1^2+1 = 7$$

Answer (score 0):

Use the property that 
$$\delta [g(x)]= \sum_i \frac{\delta(x-x_i)}{\left| g'(x_i)\right|}$$
then,
$$\delta(x^2-3x+2)=\frac{\delta(x-1)}{1}+\frac{\delta(x-2)}{1}$$
For more information check this post:
[Dirac Delta Function of a Function](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/276583/dirac-delta-function-of-a-function)