# Integrating Dirac delta functions with trigonometric arguments

Tags: integration, definite-integrals, fourier-transform, dirac-delta, trigonometric-integrals

I am not sure about how to integrate Dirac delta functions which have trigonometric arguments. I am currently trying to work out 
 
$\int_{0}^{2\pi} \delta(\cos(\theta)-k)d\theta$, $\lvert k \rvert$ < $1$. 
 
 What is the best way to approach this?

Comment: The best way?  First find a rigorous definition of the delta "function".  Then a definition of a "composition" of the form $\cos(u(\theta))$.  Without such a definition, you can prove nothing.

Comment: There is a formula: $$\delta(f(x)) = \sum_{f(x_i)=0} \frac{\delta(x-x_i)}{|f'(x_i)|}.$$
The summation notation here means that a sum is taken over every zero $x_i$ of $f$.

Comment: As GEdgar says, essentially you should study distributions. However you can get away with a change of variable ($\cos(\theta)=x$). Watch out that the function is not invertible on the whole interval, so you have to be a bit careful and split the integral in regions where $\cos$ can be inverted. The result is a general formula that you can find in Wikipedia (I'm pretty sure)

Comment: ..or up here (from md2perpe)

Comment: This is probably handled in the answers to [Dirac Delta Function of a Function](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/276583).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There is a formula for $\delta(f(x))$:
$$\delta(f(x)) = \sum_{f(x_i)=0} \frac{\delta(x-x_i)}{|f'(x_i)|}.$$

In our case we have $f(\theta) = \cos(\theta)-k,$ the zeros of which are $\theta_1=\arccos(k)$ and $\theta_2=2\pi-\arccos(k).$ This gives us
$$\begin{align}
\delta(\cos(\theta)-k) 
&= \frac{\delta(\theta-\arccos(k))}{|-\sin(\arccos(k))|}
+ \frac{\delta(\theta-(2\pi-\arccos(k)))}{|-\sin(2\pi-\arccos(k))|} \\
&= \frac{\delta(\theta-\arccos(k))}{\sqrt{1-k^2}}
+ \frac{\delta(\theta-(2\pi-\arccos(k)))}{\sqrt{1-k^2}}
\end{align}$$
so
$$
\int_{0}^{2\pi} \delta(\cos(\theta)-k)
= \int_{0}^{2\pi} \left( \frac{\delta(\theta-\arccos(k))}{\sqrt{1-k^2}}
+ \frac{\delta(\theta-(2\pi-\arccos(k)))}{\sqrt{1-k^2}} \right) d\theta 
= \frac{2}{\sqrt{1-k^2}}
.
$$

Comment: Thanks, this was really helpful. How were the limits used in the integration? What would happen if we chose another interval such as to $0$ to $\pi$ – would this halve the answer?

Comment: The only thing that matters regarding the limits is the number of zeros between them. So integrating from $0$ to $\pi$ would halve the result.