# How can I find an operator that returns $\frac{dx(t)}{dt}\delta(y-x(t))$ when acting on $\delta(y-x(t))$

Tags: operator-theory, dirac-delta, differential-operators

I'm trying to find an operator that will extract the quantity $\frac{dx(t)}{dt}$ from the function $\delta(y - x(t))$. My attempt is to get something close and then subtract the part that isn't the expression. For example I tried this operator
$$\frac{d}{dt}y$$
Applying this operator to the delta function gives
$$\frac{d}{dt}(y \delta(y - x(t)))$$
Using the picking property of the delta function
$$\frac{d}{dt}(x(t) \delta(y - x(t)))$$
Using the chain rule
$$\frac{dx(t)}{dt} \delta(y - x(t)) + \frac{d\delta(y - x(t))}{dt} x(t)$$
The goal is to get to this
$$\hat{D}\delta(y - x(t)) = \frac{dx(t)}{dt} \delta(y - x(t))$$
I already have this expression in one of my terms. I was thinking of subtracting this term off with another operator so I tried this
$$y \frac{d}{dt} $$
However applying this on the delta function doesn't give back the second term I want to get rid of.

--------------- EDIT -------------

Ive been messing around with other operators the most promising one is
$$\frac{d}{dt}$$
Applying this on the delta function gives
$$\frac{d\delta(y - x(t))}{dt}$$
Using the chain rule this becomes
$$\frac{dx}{dt}\frac{d\delta(y - x(t))}{dx}$$
Is there any identities or something I can use to remove the derivative from the delta function. Maybe a modified form of the identity:
$$\frac{d\delta(y - x)}{dy} f(y) = f(x)\delta ' (y - x) - f'(x)\delta(y - x)$$
Many Thanks Josh.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Dirac Delta Function of a Function](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/276583/dirac-delta-function-of-a-function)

Comment: @CameronWilliams Unfortunately it does not as that is when you integrate the delta function

Comment: The top equation is the relevant one here.

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/128809/discussion-on-question-by-joshua-pasa-how-can-i-find-an-operator-that-returns).

Comment: @XanderHenderson he put the answer in there, the one you removed.

Comment: @JoshuaPasa Answering in comments is not appropriate.  Comments are *intentionally* ephemeral, and are likely to be deleted at any time.  That being said, I did not remove any comments.  I merely moved them to chat.  No content has been lost.