# Meaning of $\delta(x^n)$

Tags: integration, distribution-theory, dirac-delta

Does $\delta(x^n)$ make sense? I guess that naively we could define, for example for $n=2$: $$\delta(x^2)=\lim_{a\rightarrow0}\frac{1}{2|a|}(\delta(x-a)+\delta(x+a))$$

But it seems to me that it would make any integral diverges.

Comment: Are you using [this](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/276583/dirac-delta-function-of-a-function)?

Comment: You are correct that $\delta(x^n)$ doesn't make sense for $n>1$ or for any $\delta(f(x))$ having $f'(0)=0.$