# delta function with uniform distribution

Tags: calculus, integration, dirac-delta

> I am trying to evaluate the integral, that comes from a physics problem, where i need to calculate the probability of hitting a crocodile 100 meters away from the launching point and the crocodile is 7 meters long. The initial velocity is 50ms^2. I used this integral to evaluate that but I am having a hard time with the calculus.
> $$
> f(x)=\int_0^{\pi/2}d\theta\tfrac{2}{\pi}\delta\mathopen{}\left(x-\tfrac{v_i^2\sin(2\theta)}{g}\right)\mathclose{}.
> $$
> This represents the probability of a projectile hitting a certain target 100 meters away with a given initial speed $v_i$.

I have to perform a change of variable to apply one of the properties of the delta function, but the problem is the sine function. I know I have to separate into intervals from 0 to pi/4 and pi/4 to pi/2, so I can perform a substitution and use the proprities of delta, but the density comes from a uniform distribution which in this case is 2/pi. So how do I evaluate what is inside the delta function? I dont know how to interpret.

Comment: Are you sure the integral you are calculating is correct? There is no “7” appearing anywhere? Besides that, it is highly non-standard for me to see the Dirac delta composed with a function, but if you are sure about it I think I could try to give a meaning to that in an answer

Comment: well that function inside delta is the range equation that you get when analyzing projectiles that launched with initial conditions like velocity. The lenght comes into play the range isnt infinite, so it hit anywhere in the crocodile, but i am not sure how to take conclusions from that. I wasnt able to evaluate the integral because I dont know how.

Comment: You might consider Lorenzo's comment.  But if you can satisfy yourself there, the first expression in the question at https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/276583/dirac-delta-function-of-a-function should help evaluate the integral.

Answer (score 1):

I am applying what I think is the standard definition of the composition between a Dirac delta and a smooth function (see e.g. https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dirac_delta_function#Composition_with_a_function , section “Composition with a function”).

Applying the formula you see in the Wikipedia’s page, you have
$$
\int_0^{\pi/2}d\theta\tfrac{2}{\pi}\delta\mathopen{}\left(x-\tfrac{v_i^2\sin(2\theta)}{g}\right)\mathclose{}= \sum_{\theta_0}\int_0^{\pi/2}d\theta\tfrac{2}{\pi}\frac{\delta(\theta-\theta_0)}{|h’(\theta_0)|},
$$

where $h(\theta)= x-\tfrac{v_i^2\sin(2\theta)}{g}$ and $\theta_0$ are the points where $h(\theta_0)=0$.

You clearly have $h’(\theta)=-2\frac{v_i^2\cos(2\theta)}{g}$. Since you have
$$h(\theta_0)=0\iff \sin(2\theta)=\frac{gx}{v_i^2},$$

using trigonometric formulas, you obtain
$$h’(\theta_0)=\pm\frac{2v_i^2}{g}\sqrt{1-\left(\frac{gx}{v_i^2}\right)^2}.$$

At this point, we shall make clear that we have two zeroes of $h$ if $gx<v^2$, one zero of $h$ if the equality holds, and no zeroes if $gx>v_i^2$.

So, for $x>\frac{v_i^2}{g}$, $f(x)=0$, while for $x<\frac{v_i^2}{g}$ we should have
$$f(x)= \frac{2}{\pi}\frac{g}{v_i^2}\frac{1}{\sqrt{1-\left(\frac{gx}{v_i^2}\right)^2}}.$$

Edit:
I think that the result is consistent, as there is no chance that we get beyond $x=\frac{v_i^2}{g}$, that is precisely the formula for the maximum range. Moreover, the integral of $f$ is $1$, thus it is actually a probability distribution!

Comment: Can you apply this propriety even though the function is subtracted by x, inside delta?  You are using h(theta)=0 but the delta function isnt centered at zero.

Comment: You are right, that was a typo, the delta is centered at $\theta_0$ by the formula on Wikipedia’s page. Now corrected

Comment: By the way, i am assuming that on the left hand side we have $\delta(h(\theta))$, where $\delta$ is centered at $0$, as I am putting $x$ inside $h$.

Comment: By the way, if wanted to use the propriety that is  the integral of f(x)*delta(x-a) = f(a) with the limits of integration from 0 to pi/2, would be easier? I tried that way but i couldnt finish. And thank you for the help!!

Comment: The problem with that formula is that you have to get rid of the function inside the delta first. That’s why I have applied that definition. After I got rid of that, I have just used the formula you wrote to evaluate the integral

Comment: You are welcome! It has been fun to think about this :D