# Function derivative of an integral having that function

Tags: calculus, integration, derivatives

Let $L(x) = \int_{1}^{x}f(t)dt$, can I say that $\frac{\partial L(x)}{\partial f(x)} = \frac{f(x)}{f'(x)}$?

Proof) $\frac{\partial L(x)}{\partial f(x)} = \frac{\partial L(x)}{\partial x}\frac{\partial x}{\partial f(x)} = \frac{f(x)}{f'(x)}$

Comment: No. ${}{}{}{}{}$

Comment: Is there anwer form for the derivative of $\frac{\partial L(x)}{\partial f(x)}$? Could you tell me what I am wrong for the proof?

Comment: There is a first notational issue: $L(x) = \int_{1}^{x}f(x)dx$ should be $L(x) = \int_{1}^{x}f(t)dt$ (you cannot have the same letter for a bound and for the integration variable).

Comment: What is wrong is that it's a **formal** manipulation, but how do you **define** the derivation with respect to a function ? There is a framework in which - perhaps - this computation (derivation with respect to a function) could make sense, it's the so-called "calculus of variations"

Comment: Thank for pointing out that. I just changed dx to dt :)

Comment: If $f$ and $g$ are both differentiable at $x$, $f'(x)\neq 0$, then you may define $$
\frac{{\partial g(x)}}{{\partial f(x)}} = \mathop {\lim }\limits_{h \to 0} \frac{{g(x + h) - g(x)}}{{f(x + h) - f(x)}}.
$$ But this would be just $g'(x)/f'(x)$.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yeah, it's true but there are some other conditions to be mentioned.
Let $f$ be any continuous and differentiable function in the interval $[1,x]$ for some $x\in\mathbb{R}$. And $f'(v)\neq 0$ for $v\in[1,x]$. Now denote,
$$L(x)=\int_{1}^{x}f(u) du$$
By the fundamental theorem of calculus we have that,
$$L'(x)=f(x)$$
$$\frac{dL}{dx}=f(x)$$
Similarly we have that,
$$f'(x)=\frac{df}{dx}$$
Their ratio gives,
$$\frac{dL}{df}=\frac{f(x)}{f'(x)}$$
As required.

Comment: You should assume $f'(x)\neq 0$. How do you define $dL/df$?

Comment: You don't need $f'>0$, $f'<0$ is also fine. You need $f'(x)\neq 0$ for that particular $x$.

Comment: I define it as ratio between two infinitesimals @Gary. As we are working in field of reals we have that limit definition of derivatives is same thing as $\frac{df}{dx}$. It might change strictly if we work with hyperreals (Model theory and non standard analysis and such stuff)

Comment: I understand $df(x)/dx$, but I am asking for the definition of $dL/df$.

Comment: You need $f'(x)$ for that particular $x$ not for the whole interval.

Comment: I define it as ratio between $\frac{dL}{dx}$ and $\frac{df}{dx}$.

Comment: I see. But there is almost nothing to prove here.

Comment: @Gary, Since we are defining $L(x)$ I think we need $f'(v)$ in that entire interval.

Comment: It seemed to me that you are differentiating at a particular $x$.

Comment: To define $L(x)$ I need f to be defined in that entire interval. But to clarify op's question we are required to consider f at x too.

Comment: But $f$ (and $L$) being defined on that interval has nothing to do with $f' \neq 0$ on that interval. The only point where $f' \neq 0$ is needed is the last step, where $f'(x)\neq 0$ is needed for that particular $x$.

Comment: The presence of $f'(x)$ in the denominator reminds me of a useful formula: $\delta(f(x))=\textstyle \sum_i\frac{\delta(x-a_i)}{\lvert f^\prime(a_i)\rvert}$ as given [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/276583/dirac-delta-function-of-a-function).