# Closed form of $\int_0^{\pi\text{ or }\frac\pi2}\cos(w (\cos(t)+a t-b))dt$.

Tags: definite-integrals, closed-form, dirac-delta, bessel-functions, transcendental-equations

Although an integral for $x=\dots$ exists, it is slightly harder to integrate.  [**Dirac $\delta(t)$**](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/276583/dirac-delta-function-of-a-function) helps solve $\cos(x)+ax=b$: $$\frac1{\sin(x)-a}=\int_a^b \delta(\cos(t)+at-b)dt\tag1$$ From numerical testing, $a,b$ have little effect on the integral convergence. Now use an [$\delta(t)$ integral representation](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input?i=diracdelta%28t%29+integral+representation) with $a=0,b=\pi,\frac\pi2$. The integration order is interchangeable and comparing a [double integral](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input?i=double+integral&assumption=%7B%22F%22%2C+%22DoubleIntegral%22%2C+%22rangeend2%22%7D+-%3E%22100000%22&assumption=%7B%22F%22%2C+%22DoubleIntegral%22%2C+%22rangeend1%22%7D+-%3E%22pi%2F2%22&assumption=%7B%22C%22%2C+%22double+integral%22%7D+-%3E+%7B%22Calculator%22%7D&assumption=%7B%22F%22%2C+%22DoubleIntegral%22%2C+%22integrand%22%7D+-%3E%221%2Fpi+cos%28w+%28cos%28t%29%2B0.577+t-+0.915%29%29%22&assumption=%7B%22F%22%2C+%22DoubleIntegral%22%2C+%22intvariable1%22%7D+-%3E%22t%22&assumption=%7B%22F%22%2C+%22DoubleIntegral%22%2C+%22rangestart1%22%7D+-%3E%220%22&assumption=%7B%22F%22%2C+%22DoubleIntegral%22%2C+%22intvariable2%22%7D+-%3E%22w%22&assumption=%7B%22F%22%2C+%22DoubleIntegral%22%2C+%22rangestart2%22%7D+-%3E%220%22) with its [single delta integral](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input?i=integral%5Bdelta%28cos%28t%29%2B577%2F1000t-915%2F1000%29%2C%7Bt%2C0%2Cpi%2F2%7D%5D) shows that $(2)$ probably approaches $(1)$

$$\frac1{\sin(x)-a} =\frac1\pi\int_0^\pi\int_0^\infty\cos(w (\cos(t)+a t-b))dwdt= \frac1\pi\int_0^\infty\int_0^\pi\cos(w (\cos(t)+a t-b))dtdw\tag2$$ Now we see a familiar [Bessel](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input?i=BesselJ+integral+representation),[Struve H$_v(x)$](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input?i=StruveH+integral+representation) or [Anger](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input?i=AngerJ%28v%2Cu%2Cx%29+integral+representation)-[Weber](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input?i=WeberE%28v%2Cu%2Cx%29+integral+representation) integral representation, like for the [**Kepler equation series**](https://analyticphysics.com/Classical%20Mechanics/Explicit%20Temporal%20Evolution%20for%20the%20Kepler%20Problem.htm), which is a slightly different integrand from the problem we have. Other partial results are: $$\int_0^\frac\pi2 \cos(u\cos(t)+t)dt=\frac\pi2\text H_{-1}(u)+\frac{\cos(u)-1}u$$ if one uses a $\cos(a+b)$ formula, then we [have](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input?i=integral+cos%28a+x%29+cos%28b+cos%28x%29%29+from+0+to+pi%2F2) the [hypergeometric $_1\text F_2(a;b,c;z)$](https://functions.wolfram.com/HypergeometricFunctions/Hypergeometric1F2/), likely in terms of the above functions: $$\int_0^\frac\pi2 \cos(at)\cos(b\cos(t))dt=\frac1a\sin\left(\frac{ab}2\right)\,_1\text F_2\left(1;1-\frac a2,1+\frac a2;-\frac{b^2}4\right)$$ Integration by parts on the integrand does not remove the $t$ making application of similar formulas to the above fail. What is a closed form of $\displaystyle\int_0^{\pi\text{ or }\frac\pi2}\cos(w (\cos(t)+a t-b))dt $?

Comment: What was the modification that was made 20 hours before this comment?